# WPF Label in StackPanel does not resize if Content is changed at load

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Please have a look at the data bound `Label`, that doesn't get resized at load. It works afterwards, when selecting different items in the `ListView` (but they must have different lengths!).

Definition of "getting resized":
Normally, the label adjusts its width automatically to fit the content. In my exploit, this doesn't happen. Content gets cut off.

For sure, it has to be s. th. to do with the fact, that I implemented an automatic selection mechanism via the dedicated property `AutoSelect` of `Item`.

How can I solve this problem, while preserving the autoselection logic?
Please let the possibility of multiselection out of the equation, as this does not relate to this problem.

---

**View:**

```cs
<Window x:Class="TestApp___WPF_ListView.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp___WPF_ListView"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 10">
            <Label Content="{Binding SelectedItemName}" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" />
            <Label Content="Other Text" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="listview" ItemsSource="{Binding TvItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding AutoSelect}" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

**ViewModel:**

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestApp___WPF_ListView
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Item m_SelectedItem = null;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void DoPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }

        public Item SelectedItem
        {
            get
            {
                return m_SelectedItem;
            }

            set
            {
                m_SelectedItem = value;
                DoPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
                DoPropertyChanged("SelectedItemName");
            }
        }

        public string SelectedItemName { get { return m_SelectedItem?.Name ?? "null"; }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            Items.Add(new Item("Item #1 asölkasd", false));
            Items.Add(new Item("Item #2 as", false));
            Items.Add(new Item("Item #3 asdköwowfialöafl", false));
            Items.Add(new Item("Item #4 akksad", true));
            Items.Add(new Item("Item #5 aöasölskfawelllkasdlk", false));
            Items.Add(new Item("Item #6 aslsdkföwl", false));
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Data Item:**

```cs
namespace TestApp___WPF_ListView
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool AutoSelect { get; set; }

        public Item(string p_Name, bool p_AutoSelect)
        {
            Name = p_Name;
            AutoSelect = p_AutoSelect;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course it took me some hours to identify this root cause of the problem out of the real business application... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change when you load your view model from in the XAML to in the loaded statement resolves the issue. The issue is view model is being created before the view so no notifications are telling the view to be update. Once one clicks on an item in the list the view is updated receives a notification event and everything is update correctly.

Remove:

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
```

Add:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart, this works! I am losing the ability to have a content preview in the designer, though. While this is not mission critical of course, please let me know if there is another alternative.

Comment: I have had issues with this as well I have not found any really good solutions for this though